# Approach to simplify step function

Tags: step

I have the following step function:

```
(5t + 20)[u(t + 4) − u(t + 2)] − 5t[u(t + 2) − u(t − 2)] + (5t − 20)[u(t − 2) − u(t − 4)]
```

The solution simplifies it to:

```
5(t + 4)u(t + 4) − 10(t + 2)u(t + 2) + 10(t − 2)u(t − 2) − 5(t − 4)u(t − 4)
```

I do not understand how the simplification is done. I understand why

`(5t+20) = 5(t+4)`

but the rest I do not understand. Can someone please enlighten me?

Comment: Would this be better asked on [Mathematics Stack Exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be just the distributive law of standard algebra :-)

For instance, take a look at `u(t+2)`, from the first term you have:

```
(-5t-20) u(t+2)
```

and from the second:

```
(-5t) u(t+2)
```

combining the coefficients we get:

```
-5t - 20 - 5t = -10t - 20 = -10(t + 2).
```

Answer (score 0):

You had the following step function:

```
(5t + 20)[u(t + 4) − u(t + 2)] − 5t[u(t + 2) − u(t − 2)] + (5t − 20)[u(t − 2) − u(t − 4)]
```

**Assigning Variables:**

Let unit steps:

```
 u(t + 4) = a
 u(t - 4) = b
 u(t + 2) = c
 u(t − 2) = d
```

So now we have:

```
(5t + 20)(a - c) -5t(c - d) + (5t - 20)(d - b)
```

**Simplification:**

```
= 5ta + 20a - 5tc -20c -5tc +5td +5td +20d -5tb + 20b      //Expand it out
= 5(t+4)a -10(t+2)c +10(t-2)d -5(t-4)b                     //Group like terms
= 5(t+4)u(t+4) -10(t+2)u(t+2) +10(t-2)u(t-2) -5(t−4)u(t−4) //Add step functions back
```

And there we go, you have:

1. `5(t+4)u(t+4)` a ramp function starting at -4 with a gradient of 5. (zero for all values less than -4 seconds)
2. `-10(t+2)u(t+2)` a ramp function starting at time -2 with gradient -10 (zero for all values less than -2 seconds)
3. `+10(t-2)u(t-2)` a ramp function starting at time 2 with gradient 10 (zero for all values less than 2 seconds)
4. `-5(t−4)u(t−4)` a ramp function starting at time 4 with gradient -5 (zero for all values less than 4 seconds)

Sum that all together and you get a triangle pulse with the following points of interest: `(-4,0)` ; `(-2,10)` ; `(0,0)` ; `(2,-10)` ; `(4,0)`

See graph on Wolfram alpha: [Here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5(t%2B4)(unitStep(t%2B4))%20-10(t%2B2)(unitStep(t%2B2))%20%2B10(t-2)(unitStep(t-2))%20-5(t%E2%88%924)(unitStep(t%E2%88%924)))

**Computer Applications** *as this is stack overflow and not math.stackexchange*

Triangle waves (like this) are necessary for generating pure sinusoidal waveforms (analog signals) by comparing them to a square waves with varying duty cycle (PWM). It is fundamentally how DAC's (Digital to analog converters) work and how our old analog devices use to interface with our computers. It is also how AC power is converted from DC, by the use of an inverter.